# How to list all schemas and switch to one in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I'm new to ClickHouse and I'm trying to use the CLI client.
What's the Clickhouse way to select all schemas and then select one?
I mean the equivalent of Oracle's

```
select username from sys.all_users
alter session set current_schema = otheruser;
```

Or Postgres's

```
\list
set search_path to 'schema_name'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a bit of searching I found the answer.

```
show databases
SELECT currentDatabase()
```

This helps you see where you are and what are all the databases (schemas) you can go to.
Then...

```
use database_name
```

Allows you to select the one you want to work with.